# Partial view inputs not binding to BindProperty model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a back-end code:

```
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    private readonly AppDbContext context;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment webhostenvironment;

    [BindProperty] public Client Client { get; set; }
    [BindProperty] public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }

   

    public SignUpModel(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository, AppDbContext context, IWebHostEnvironment webhostenvironment)
    {
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        this.context = context;
        this.webhostenvironment = webhostenvironment;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet(int? id)
    {
        if (id.HasValue)
        {
            Client = employeeRepository.GetClient(id);
        }

        return Page();
    }

public IActionResult OnPost(int? id)
{
    try
    {
        if (!id.HasValue)
        {
            ModelState.Remove("ClientId");
            ModelState.Remove("photoPath");
            
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = employeeRepository.Check(Client.username, Client.password);

                if (result != null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Username and/or Password already exists! Please choose another.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Client.photoPath = employeeRepository.ProcessUploadedFile(Photo);

                    var newid = employeeRepository.InsertClient(Client.ClientName, Client.username, Client.password, Client.photoPath);

                    // Redirect to the user's profile page
                    return RedirectToPage("/Profile", new { id = newid });
                }
            }
        else
        {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(webhostenvironment.WebRootPath,
                    "images", Client.photoPath);

                System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);

                // Save the new photo in wwwroot/images folder and update
                // PhotoPath property of the employee object

                Client.photoPath = employeeRepository.ProcessUploadedFile(Photo);

                var newid = employeeRepository.UpdateClient(Client.ClientId, Client.ClientName, Client.username, Client.password, Client.photoPath);

                return RedirectToPage("/Profile", new { id = newid });
        }
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
    {
        foreach (var modelStateKey in ModelState.Keys)
        {
            foreach (var error in ModelState[modelStateKey].Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"This is in catch: {modelStateKey}: {error.ErrorMessage}");
            }
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"This is in catch: {ex.Message}");
    }

    // Authentication failed, return to login page
    return Page();
}
```

that inserts or updates records in a database depending if OnPost id parameter has a value. If there is none, user is creating a new profile; if there is, user is updating an existing one.

The following is the front-end code:

```
    @page "/SignUp/{id:min(1)?}"
    @model ActualProject.Pages.SignUpModel
    @{

        ViewData["title"] = "SignUp";
        ViewData["ShowName"] = true;

        var pageHeader = Model.Client != null ? "/Profile" : "/Login";
        var buttonText = pageHeader == "/Profile" ? "Back to Profile" : "Back to Login";
        var buttonText2 = buttonText == "Back to Profile" ? "Update" : "Sign Up";
    }

    <h2>Sign Up</h2>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        @if (Model.Client != null && Model.Client.ClientId != null)
        {
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Client.ClientId"/>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Client.photoPath"/>
        }

        <partial name="_LoginFieldsPartial" model="@Model.Client" />

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="Photo" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>

            <div class="col-sm-10">

                <div class="custom-file">

                    <input asp-for="Photo" class="custom-file-input form-control">
                    <label class="custom-file-label">Click here to change photo</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a asp-page="@pageHeader" class="btn btn-primary">@buttonText</a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">@buttonText2</button>

        @section Scripts {
            <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
        }

    </form>
```

And the remaining code is the partial view "_LoginFieldsPartial":

```
    @model Client
    @{
        var showName = (bool)ViewData["ShowName"];
    }


    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>

    @if (showName)
    {
        <div>
            <label asp-for="@Model.ClientName">Your Name</label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.ClientName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ClientName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        <label asp-for="@Model.username"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.username" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.username" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label asp-for="@Model.password"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.password" type="password" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.password" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

**Problem**

The insertion of records work flawlessly; it's the **updating** of records that causes errors. Specifically, the values in **partial view** is not binding and they're passing null values instead. This is the update function:

```
    public Client UpdateClient(int clientId, string clientname, string username, string password, string filepath)
    {
        var existingClient = context.Clients.Find(clientId);

        if (existingClient != null)
        {
            // Update the properties with the new values
            existingClient.ClientName = clientname;
            existingClient.username = username;
            existingClient.password = password;
            existingClient.photoPath = filepath;

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return existingClient;
    }
```

The error is triggered by `context.SaveChanges();`; when I checked the debugger, my ClientName, username, & password values are all **null**. I'm confused because as I said, the insertion of records work flawlessly; all the values are bound correctly with the exception of Client.ClientId (because it's assumed no ClientId means the user is creating a new profile).

When I access the Sign Up page with an id, the values from Client variable in OnGet() are displayed in the partial view fields. Somehow, only during updating, the input fields in partial view are not binding. I've also tried using ModelStates but the same error persists which is why I removed them.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @N. Tanaka, any update here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your main view and partial view input naming rule does not match.

For update operation, the `ClientId` and `photoPath` inputs' name are `Client.propertyName`. But the partial view inputs' name are `propertyName`,you could F12 to check the rendered html code in the `Elements` panel in the browser.

One way is that you could specify the name:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Client.ClientId" name="ClientId"/>
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Client.photoPath" name="photoPath" />
```

Another way is to use the following code to make the partial view render the input with name `Client.propertyName`:

```
<partial name="_LoginFieldsPartial" for="@Model.Client" />
```

Comment: Hello @Rena. I extremely apologize for the late reply. Your 2nd solution doesn't work because the "for" tag can't be used with "partial" tag; your 1st solution does! Thanks!

Before I mark it as answered, may I ask why does the first solution work? Why does the naming rule matter here when all of them refer to the same model Client?

Comment: Hi @N.Tanaka, have you tried the for? It can be used with partial tag. For why second solution works, I explained in my answer at the beginning, you main view input name rule do not match the partial view. It will override the asp-for generated default name when you specify the name attribute.